# Characterisation of non-closed ideals in $C[0,1]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, ideals, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $C[0,1]$ be the $C^*$-algebra of continuous functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb C$.

I understand that the *closed* (two-sided, $*$-closed) ideals in $C[0,1]$ are in correspondence with the closed subspaces of $[0,1]$, with the correspondence is given by assigning to a subspace the set of functions that vanish on it.

What happens if one wants to look at the set of *all* (not-necessarily closed) ideals in $C[0,1]$, which we now view just as a commutative $\mathbb C$-algebra? From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158397/non-closed-ideals-in-c-algebras), I see that such ideals do exist.

**Question 1:** Does the set of not necessarily closed ideals in $C[0,1]$ have an easy description?

**Question 2:** More generally, does there exist such a description for $C_0(X)$ for some locally compact Hausdorff space $X$?

*Comment:* I would guess that if $I$ is an ideal (not necessarily closed) of $C_0(X)$, there would have to be a point in $X$ at which all functions in $I$ vanish simultaneously, but it's just a guess.

Comment: Your final guess, equivalent to the description of the maximal ideals, is correct but I don't think it helps.

Comment: maybe this is not very helpful: for any set $S\subset X$, the set $I_S$ of continuous functions vanishing precisely at $S$ is an ideal in $C(X)$; note that we can have $I_S=I_T$ even for $S\ne T$ (e.g. $S=X$, $T=X\setminus\{x_0\}$ for some non-isolated point $x_0$). On the other hand, given an ideal $I$, its closure is a closed (self-adjoint) ideal in $C(X)$, thus in correspondence with some closed subset, but i don't see something more to say at this point

Comment: @AnneBauval I think my final guess also includes non-maximal closed ideals. If a set of functions vanishes on some common subset, then they also vanish on a common point.

Comment: @geometricK Whence my first comment. Your final guess is equivalent to "the maximal ideals are the sets of functions vanishing at a given point".